# Reference built-in Account UserId Assign to Model as Foreign Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

after looking for an answer in the already existing questions, I am still a little confused as how I should proceed.  I am new to the MVC 3 framework, so if I come off sounding like a dope, I appologize!!

Ok, so I created a MVC 3 internet application, created 3 new Users administrator, user1, and user2.  I have created a new model, and controller for my "Posts" I am able to add, edit and delete the items.  I currently have a column called UserID in my posts table.  I would like this to be automagically populated with the current UsersID.  I think I would define this in the controller like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Post post)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            public int User = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(id);

            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(post);
    }
```

Inside the model, this is what I currently have:

```
    public class Post
    {
        public int PostID { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string PostTitle { get; set; }
        public int PostType { get; set; }
        public string PostBody { get; set; }
        public string PostBlogTitle { get; set; }
        public string PostBlogURL { get; set; }
        public string PostCategory { get; set; }
        public string PostSEO { get; set; }
        public int PostStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class PostDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to replace `public int UserID { get; set; }` with my newly defined variable in the controller, but not sure where/how to add it.

Comment: Double check if your UserId info is saved in viewmodel when you post, and does it get saved in your database?

Comment: Currently in my view, I have been manually entering the userId, and it does save.  I just added this line to my code `public int User = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(id);` today and have not tested it yet, because I know something needs to get changed in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I'm clear on what you're trying to achieve.  Are you just trying to assign the current user to the model, save it and then pass it back to the view?

If so you can just do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Post post)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Note: I'm assuming this actually works/returns an int
        public int User = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(id);

        post.UserID = User;

        db.Posts.Add(post);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    return View(post);
}
```

Comment: Correct, I don't know if that works either, that is just what I found on another stackoverflow answer.  I just want to assign the current users ID to the newly added Post, but not sure where to do so.

Comment: If `System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(id)` returns the value you need, then my code I posted will work.  If you're asking where to get the ID from that's a different story.

Comment: So you don't need to change anything in the Model?

Comment: Your model has a UserID property, in my example I assign the value of that property to the ID you retrieve (`post.UserID = User`).  That's all you need to do.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, that code I had did not work, so I changed it to `Guid userGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;` But now I get an error cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Guid' to 'int'.  Do i need to change my model to a different datatype, or can this by typecasted into an int?

Comment: Nevermind, found this http://forums.asp.net/t/1266765.aspx I guess it should be a string.